# Is there a way to refer to the second last word of the previously entered command (like $^ for the first and $$ for the last word)

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-interface

In PowerShell, when entering a command, I can refer to the value of the first and last word of the most recently entered command with `$^` and `$$`. I am wondering if there is a shortcut to refer to the second last, nth last or nth word also.

Comment: Hmmm not sure if there is a shortcut but `(Get-History)[-2]` ?

Comment: If it's not listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables?view=powershell-7.1) then probably not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no direct equivalent to the [automatic variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variable) you mention, but you can combine [`Get-History`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/get-history) with PowerShell's language parser ([`System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser)) to achieve your intent:

```sh
function Get-PrevCmdLineTokens {

  # Get the previous command line's text.
  $prevCmdLine = (Get-History)[-1].CommandLine

  # Use the language parser to break it into syntactic elements.
  $tokens = $null
  $null = [System.Management.Automation.Language.Parser]::ParseInput(
    $prevCmdLine, 
    [ref] $tokens,
    [ref] $null   
  )

  # Get and output an array of the text representations of the syntactic elements,
  # (excluding the final `EndOfInput` element).
  $tokens[0..($tokens.Count - 2)].Text
 
}
```

Example:

```sh
PS> $null = Write-Output Honey "I'm $HOME"
PS> Get-PrevCmdLineTokens
```

The above yields:

```
$null
=
Write-Output
Honey
"I'm $HOME"
```

Note:

- As with `$^` and `$$`, the tokens that make up the command are *unexpanded*, meaning that they are represented *as typed* rather than by their *interpolated* value.
- However, *unlike* with `$^` and `$$`, any *syntactic quoting* is retained (e.g., `"I'm $HOME"` instead of `I'm $HOME`).

  - While you could use `.Value` instead of `.Text` in the function above in order to strip the syntactic quoting, you would then miss out on tokens such as `$null` and `=`.